# Como funciona Laravel exactamente en su modelo MVC?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

mi pregunta es sobre como funciona Laravel, se que su modelo es MVC y tambien que el que hace las transacciones es el Controlador, osea...

Vista <--------> Controlador <---------> Modelo

Pero existe algo llamado Rutes (Rutas), entonces, donde entran en juego las rutas ?
Hasta donde he podido estudiar y en mi humilde analisis, funciona asi...

Vista <-------> Rutas <--------> Controlador <-------> Modelo.

Pero claro, el Controlador ya no le responderia a las rutas, si no a la vista.

Estoy en lo correcto ?

Comment: Respecto a si Laravel es MVC, la respuesta es NO. La explicación aquí:  https://styde.net/porque-laravel-no-es-mvc-y-tu-deberias-olvidarte-de-mvc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En resumen, Laravel usa las rutas para saber cuál controlador llamar y cuál método. Luego el controlador responde de vuelta con una vista. Esto quiere decir que las rutas entran en juego antes que los controladores.

Answer (score 0):

Sumando al comentario de @PAGANA. Desde el momento que identificaste el concepto de rutas ya te podes dar cuenta que no es exclusivamente un MVC, al menos no puro. Podes usarlo como tal, pero podes hacer un montón de otras cosas

Ya no existe el concepto de modelo como tal, te permite generar la estructura de aplicación vos desees, solo limitado a tu imaginación.

De base, el framework implementa varios patrones de diseño:
El Facade se utiliza para llamar a los servicios que implementa laravel mediante el ServiceProvider.
Eloquent implementa el patrón ActiveRecord
Implementa interfaces Fluidas.
Implementa Template view con blade.

Hay varios videos y documentación donde se aplica DDD con laravel sobre aplicaciones grandes y evolutivas, algo extremadamente ambicioso para un lenguaje como php